# Фрактальные списки в Python, или Почему это так работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, фракталы

Я тут столкнулся с учебной задачей (не волнуйтесь, вопрос не про то, как ее сделать, я ее уже сделал), где нужно сделать бесконечный список следующим образом: `[0, *список*, *список еще раз*, 2]`

```
fractal = [0, 2]
fractal.insert(1, fractal)
fractal.insert(2, fractal)
```

Я эту задачу решил, но не понимаю как она работает. По идее оно просто должно вставить список [0, 2], но вставляет вместо него рекурсивный список. Как это происходит?

Comment: Дело в том, что в питоне почти все делается по ссылке - в том числе вставка списка в список. Если вы попробуете `a.append(a)`, то получите подобный результат. Тот факт, что питон это как-то отдельно обрабатывает, уже интереснее, но я не могу найти описание этого эффекта нигде, кроме как на RuSO)). В общем, когда вы пишете `fractal.insert(1, fractal)`, то вы вставляете на первое место ссылку на объект `fractal`, в котором эта ссылка и хранится.

Comment: У меня вопрос: а откуда `fractal` импортирован?

Comment: @Dmitry, fractal - это список, insert - функция списка

Comment: @EzikBro то есть получается он добавляет ссылку на список, а затем когда я обращаюсь по индексу, он выводит тот же самый список по ссылке на список?

Comment: @alex9127 тьфу, блин... это же просто переменная.... Пошел я спать)

Comment: @Dmitry бывает, не переживайте

Comment: Да, именно так. Это можно увидеть, например, так: 
`>>> fractal = [0, 2]
>>> id(fractal)
# 66317736
>>> fractal.insert(1, fractal)
>>> id(fractal)
# 66317736
>>> id(fractal[1])
# 66317736`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело все в том что в питоне списки передаются по ссылкам. То есть когда ты добавляешь в список тот же список, то он же и является тем списком который передаешь. Поэтому элементы добавляются в добавляемый список, но тогда в первый список еще добавляется и так до бесконечности.
Поэтому такой код выводит:

```
a = []
a.append(a)
print(a)
print(a[0][0][0][0][0][0][0])
```

Выводит:

```
[[...]]
[[...]]
```