# Глубина списка согласно заданному числу

Tags: python-3.x

Прошу помощи у уважаемого сообщества. Задача вроде бы простая, но я уже отчаялся сам догадаться.
Дано: целое натуральное число (n = 5, например).
Необходимо: получить список вложенных списков глубины равной заданному числу. (например: [[[[[]]]]])
Пробовал:

```py
     n = 3  
     a = []
     ans = []
      while n > 0:
        ans.append(a)
        a = ans
        n -= 3
        ans.append(a)
```

но выдает:

```
[[], [...]]
```

попробовал схитрить:

```
n = 6
print(eval(n*'['+n*']'))
```

но второй способ переполняет память "проверяльщика".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, наведите на путь истинный.

Полсе подсказки попробовал рекурсию, но ответ у меня все равно получился далеко от ожидаемого:

```
n = 3
a = []
ans = []
def arr(a, ans):
    ans.append(a)
    return a
while n > 0:
    a = arr(a, ans)
    n -= 1
print(ans)
```

ответ: [[], [], []]
Кроме того, впервые встретил такого зверя: [...], и даже не смог загуглить что это...

Comment: Задачка как я понимаю на рекурсию

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, наваял такое:

Comment: n = 3
a = []
ans = []
def arr(a, ans):
    ans.append(a)
    return a
while n > 0:
    a = arr(a, ans)
    n -= 1
print(ans)

Comment: Так в ответ и впишите, рабочий код. Вдруг кому и пригодится

Comment: Да даже без рекурсии просто в две строки `a = []` и `for _ in range(1, n): a = [a]`

Comment: Решение например такое: ```def func(depth): if depth == 1: return [] else: return [func(depth - 1)]```
А [...] - это элемент списка, который этим списком и является, подробной информации я не имею, но на SO было небольшое объяснение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373519

Comment: Премного благодарен всем за советы и подсказки!  Воспользовался решением andreymal, как самым простым. Думал в этом направлении но не смог реализовать этот способ:)